# How to undo the split view in VS2013?

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2013

I've downloaded the VS2013 Preview (Express, Windows Desktop if you're wondering/affects this). I've got a small issue though. I have the split view. I quite like it. Sometimes I have to get back into non-split view. However, the only way to do this as far as I know (at least in the C# code editor) is to close VS and open it again. This is pretty annoying. Is there any other way of un-splitting the view?

If you don't know what I'm talking about:
[image: How do I unsplit this?]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hover over the middle section and drag it all the way back to the top

Where shown in image[image: Visual Studio 2012]

Comment: A banausic solution. This will not remove or undo the split.

Comment: @Kaiyakha I've upvoted your solution, good work.  Originally this wasn't there in VS2013 to my knowledge happy to see there is now this choice as well.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2017 `Window` -> `Remove Split`. Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Look near the top. The  -> Split. That should unsplit the view. Lots of other useful window arrangement views there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In current version, as of this writing, it's under View -> Editor Layout -> Single